# debugging dll in vb.net web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, dll

I have a vb.net web application in visual web developer 2008 with a dll file and i need to debug a method in that dll.

I also have project source files for the dll file itself. How could i make the web application use the source instead of the dll file so that i'd be able to debug it?

I've tried debugging the dll project itself, but it's not a very good solution, because it seems the dll depends on the web application settings and data and it would simply be too much work to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your web application running locally, open up your DLL project and then attach the debugger to IIS.

Comment: Already solved with adding a dll together with pdb file to the bin directory of the project. I don't have iis, i use visual web developer. Thanks for the help.